# How to detect if NSString contains a particular character or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have one NSString object , for ex:- ($45,0000)

Now i want to find if this string contains () or not

How can i do this?

Comment: Up voted because the question is straightforward and was useful.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Are you trying to find if it contains at least one of `(` or `)`? You can use `-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`:

```
NSCharacterSet *cset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
NSRange range = [mystr rangeOfCharacterFromSet:cset];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    // no ( or ) in the string
} else {
    // ( or ) are present
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The method below will return Yes if the given string contains the given char

```
-(BOOL)doesString:(NSString *)string containCharacter:(char)character
{
    return [string rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character]].location != NSNotFound;
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
 NSString *s = @"abcdefg";

    if ([self doesString:s containCharacter:'a'])
        NSLog(@"'a' found");
    else
        NSLog(@"No 'a' found");


    if ([self doesString:s containCharacter:'h'])
        NSLog(@"'h' found");
    else
        NSLog(@"No 'h' found");
```

Output:

2013-01-11 11:15:03.830 CharFinder[17539:c07] 'a' found

2013-01-11 11:15:03.831 CharFinder[17539:c07] No 'h' found

Comment: how about just
    `return [string rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",character]].location != NSNotFound;`

Answer (score 2):

```
- (bool) contains: (NSString*) substring {
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:substring];
    return range.location != NSNotFound;
}
```

Comment: This answer is clean.

Answer (score 2):

I got a generalized answer to your question which I was using in my code. This code includes the following rules:
1. No special characters 
2. At least one capital and one small English alphabet
3. At least one numeric digit

```
 BOOL lowerCaseLetter,upperCaseLetter,digit,specialCharacter;
    int asciiValue;
    if([txtPassword.text length] >= 5)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < [txtPassword.text length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [txtPassword.text characterAtIndex:i];
            if(!lowerCaseLetter)
            {
                lowerCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
            }
            if(!upperCaseLetter)
            {
                upperCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
            }
            if(!digit)
            {
                digit = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
            }

            asciiValue = [txtPassword.text characterAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"ascii value---%d",asciiValue);
            if((asciiValue >=33&&asciiValue < 47)||(asciiValue>=58 && asciiValue<=64)||(asciiValue>=91 && asciiValue<=96)||(asciiValue>=91 && asciiValue<=96))
            {
                specialCharacter=1;
            }
            else
            {
                specialCharacter=0;
            }

        }

        if(specialCharacter==0 && digit && lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter)
        {
            //do what u want
            NSLog(@"Valid Password %d",specialCharacter);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid Password %d",specialCharacter);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Please Ensure that you have at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and No Any special character"
                                                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why to always use for NSCharactorSet ?? this is simple and powerful  solution

```
NSString *textStr = @"This is String Containing / Character";

if ([textStr containsString:@"/"])
{
    NSLog(@"Found!!");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Not Found!!");
```

Comment: Well, because the question was asking for finding if it contained '(' or ')'

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
NSString rangeOfString: (NSString *) string
```

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:

If the NSRange comes back with property 'location' equal to NSNotFound, then the string does not contain the passed string (or character).

Comment: It will return NSNotFound because in his case the string is "($45,0000)" and the '(' and ')' characters are not adjacent. See Kevin's answer.

Comment: Ramy - Yes, that is correct. Forgive my lapse in memory! Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. In that case the OP string is "($45,0000)", if you compute [OPString rangeOfString: @"()"] it will *always* return NSNotFound. You have to use another method.