# Password validation in UITextfield input for password validation in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, validation, passwords, uitextfield

I want to validate my password from a textfield which has the following requirement.

1. Password must contain one capital and one small alphabet.
2. No special character is allowed.

I have tried `[[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet] characterIsMember:(my character to be tested]`, but it is not working for all characters.

Suggest me solutions for regular expression also if possible, thanks.

Comment: What does `special character` stands for in your case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if NSString contains a particular character or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266059/how-to-detect-if-nsstring-contains-a-particular-character-or-not)

Comment: As a side note, as an end user, I absolutely hate arbitrary password restrictions.  My normal, unrestricted password is far stronger than what I use when I am restricted, and I can remember my unrestricted passwords far better than restricted ones.  Instead, you should encourage the user to use a passphrase instead of a password and to consider including some amount of "1337 5p34k" without absolutely requiring any specific restrictions.

Comment: in my case special characters are all the characters except english alphabetsw(capital and small) and numbers that is 0-9

Answer (score 4):

Have a try and test.

```
- (BOOL)isPasswordValid:(NSString *)password
{
    NSCharacterSet * characterSet = [NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] ;
    NSRange range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet] ;
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO ;
    }
    characterSet = [NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] ;
    range = [password rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterSet] ;
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        return NO ;
    }

    characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"] ;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [password length]; ++i) {
        unichar uchar = [password characterAtIndex:i] ;
        if (![characterSet characterIsMember:uchar]) {
            return NO ;
        }
    }
    return YES ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For upper case and lower case you can use below code:

```
[[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[myString characterAtIndex:0]];
```

For special characters you can use below code:

```
if ([aString isMatchedByRegex:@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"]) {
  NSLog(@"This string contains illegal characters");
}
```